# Source reference for Lord Kartikeya's peeling off skin incident

Tags: shiva, ganesha, parvati, kartikeya

I came across an information that [there exists a temple for Lord Kartikeya in Kurukshetra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kartikeya_Temple,_Pehowa) where entry for women is prohibited. The reason for that is an incident in which there was a competition between Lord Kartikeya and Lord Ganesha (as described [here](http://taurian123.blogspot.in/2012/09/the-fear-of-kartikeyas-curse-lives-on.html)) and that Lord Kartikeya was so much angry with his mother Parvati that he peeled off all his skin and only his skeleton was left.

Can anyone tell me which Hindu scripture states the above version of the story?

The stories that I have read and heard till now were a bit different in which Kartikeya was just angry with Mata Parvati and he only moved away from her to South India but there was no incident of peeling off his skin.

Comment: I found references to worship of Kartikeya in this Prithudak location in both the Mahabharata and the Padma Purana.  (Of course, since it was the Dwapara Yuga there were no temples yet.) But neither one refers to Kartikeyya having no skin or women being prohibited; in fact the Padma Purana says it can get rid of "all the bad deeds done by a man or woman".

Comment: Why a downvote on this question. This temple is there in Kurukshetra and I have been hearing the same story from my childhood days about the temple as being described here and the link I posted also proves the story to be correct as per the temple's legend. On googling also, it states that women entry is prohibited in this temple. Now, its for us to dig into and find the reference. If it cannot be found in any scriptural reference then may be we are lucky that we have found a story (may be a legend/myth) which is not yet covered in books. Kind of missing link.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think your question deserves a downvote either.  By the way, references to Ganesha in Hindu scripture are few and far between (because Ganesha became popular later on), so I can try to look through those references to find the story.

Comment: @Keshav, generally stories related to Lord Ganesha are covered in Ganesh Purana and Mudgala Purana, these are said to be up-puranas but they are said to be written at later stages around AD 1100–1400, so can't comment on their correctness to actual incidents

Comment: Yeah, those works are of dubious reliability, so I want to try and see whether the Mahapuranas contain this story.  The Ganesha Purana and the Mudgala Purana aren't even on the canonical lists of Upapuranas: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upapurana

Comment: @Keshav - There is incident in principle puranas, where Kartikeya was molesting many of the women in heavenly planets. All of them went and complained to parvati. Parvati was angry with Kartikeya and cursed him saying, that when ever he approches any women, kartikeya will see only parvati in her. May be it is related to this curse by parvati on her son. But, i am not sure.

Comment: @Krishna Do you know what Puranas mentions this incident?  This is the first time I'm hearing anything negative about Muruga.

Comment: @Keshav - It is very much there in one of the principal 18 puranas...I have read it...But, dont remember the exact purana...It should be in brahma or brahmanda, most probably, i guess..

Comment: I have also heard of this story what Krishna mentioned but I am also not sure of its source.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan isn't prithudak different from Kurukshetra? It is Pehowa I think which is close by but not exactly Kurukshetra.