# Why low-caste people are not allowed inside some temples and homes?

Tags: temple, practice, culture, caste-system

In most temples and homes, especially in villages, low-caste people are not allowed.

These regulations are being followed for thousands of years now.

What is the reason behind such practice? What do scriptures say about this?

Comment: Can you give some example like which temple , which place etc.I haven't heard of such a thing.Yes in some temples people not allowed to touch murthy or allowed in "Garbha Gruha"  or inside where the main idol is placed for traditional purpose.

Comment: Related: [Why are women not allowed in the Kartikeya Temple at Pushkar?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/951)

Comment: I think the restriction may be on the outcaste not the low caste. In any case the one who knows the rules of dharma shastras and follows the restrictions of the related agamas for the temples is allowed to do worship in the temple. For example in tirupati temple no one except Vaikansa agama followers(all bramhins) are allowed to do archana in temple no one else is allowed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well,the Hindu Shastras ,mostly consider the lowest caste,the Sudra,as being impure and also consider that **they can transmit this impurity to other objects or living beings by touch or association etc.**

Similar are the rules,for the fallen caste or the outcaste or the chandala.

I'm adding here a few verses from the Parashara Smriti,which is widely regarded as the Dharma Shastra to be followed in the current Yuga i.e the Kali Yuga.

> **21. If himself unwashed, he is touched by a Shoodra, who, however, is not unwashed, — the purification is to wash himself**. If an
>   unwashed Shoodra touches an unwashed regenerate man, the latter must
>   perform the prajapatya penance
>
> 23. Bronze vessels smelt by a cow, or polluted by a dog or a crow, **or if a Shoodra has made them unclean by eating off them,** are rendered pure, when they have been ten times rubbed with ashes.
> 24. While a Brahman has not washed himself after taking his meals, **if he chances to be touched** by another yet unwashed after a meal, or by a dog, **or by a Shoodra**, he **should fast for a single night,
>       and then swallow the five articles derived from a cow, whereby purity
>       is restored to- him.**

The above verses make it clear that the Sudras have the ability to make things/beings impure by his touch.

Some more verses:

> 34. **To eat a Shoodra's food, to associate with him, to sit in the same place with, him, and receive knowledge by his instruction, would cause
>       degradation even to one who resembles the kindled fire**
> 35. **Salt, honey and oil, curded milk, whey, and milk all these are not polluted by the touch of persons of the Shoodra caste**.Shoodra may sell
>       these to all the castes.

[image]

[image]

Verse 35 clearly states that a Sudra can make many things impure simply by his touch .

The Manu Smriti states that Sudras are created out of Tamas(the mode of darkness,ignorance etc)(one of the 3 Gunas,the other two being Sattva and Rajas).

> Manu Smriti 12.43. Elephants, horses, **Sudras**, and despicable
>   barbarians, lions, tigers, and boars (are) the middling states, **caused
>   by (the quality of) Darkness.**

So,the temple priests,who are all Brahmins,might be apprehensive of the fact that ,if the Sudras by accident touch them or any other objects in Temples,might render them impure.

To make them and themselves pure again(which is of course the first necessity in rituals) would be a cumbersome job.

That is **probably** the reason why such prohibitions are there regarding the Sudras and the outcastes entering Temple premises.

Although, i don't really know which Temples actually have such restrictions.

Also, take a look at the following verse which says that it is not all about caste by birth only:

> 24. **A Brahman, ignorant of the Gayatri hymn, is more unclean than even a Shoodra** ; the Brahmans who know the nature and the sanctity
>       of the Gayatri hymn, are honored and revered by all persons(Parashara
>       Smriti)

So,even an ignorant Brahmin should be stopped from entering Temples.

But preventing Sudras from entering houses of the Higher castes **is of course not supported by Scriptures**.Because, to serve the higher castes is considered to be the only job of a Sudra.**And to serve anyone a Sudra should first be allowed entry to his house.**

[image]

The Vedas state that the Sudras are created from the feet of the Supreme Being.So,like everyone else,they are also a part of the Almighty,and they too reserve the right to worship the Almighty.

> brāhmao’sya mukham ās īt | bāhūrājanyakta  | ūrū tada sya yad vaiśya 
>   | **padbhy āgśūdro aj āyata** || 13 ||
>
> The   brahmin was his mouth,  of  both    His arms    was the Raja    made.
>   His   thighs  became  the Vaishya,    **from  His feet    was the Shudra  produced.
>   13(Purusha Suktam verse 13)**

So,i am not quite in favor of stopping them from entering Temples.

Also,its not practically possible to check either, if someone entering a Temple is a Sudra(by birth) or an ignorant Brahmin like the one described above.

Comment: How should we interpret Shudra here? The one with Tamas guna or the low caste born, as all low caste borns don't have Tamas predominantly.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Yes you are right..that's y i have mentioned in the answer that  such verification is not practically possible..Even a Brahmin who does not know the Vedas is worst than a Sudra as far as impurity is concerned..In anycase i just indicated the Scriptural basis of why such prohibitions mite be practiced in our society.. I'm in no way favoring such practices..

Comment: @TheDestroyer Sudras aren't allowed into temples only because of the touch factor i mentioned in my answer.The fear that they can touch things or beings and make them impure,which can be obsruction for rituals .Now whether this applies to Sudras by birth or to Sudras by gunas is difficult for me to decide..If its  the later then it becomes extremely hard to determine actually..

Comment: @Rickross Superb explanation.:) Adding to it: A Shudra in the original dynamic caste system is also considered a dirty individual. Anyone can be dirty, at the period one is dirty it is not appropriate to enter a temple. A home is considered as temple so it is also not permitted.

Comment: @AshishSrivastava Thanks.I had already posted an [answer](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15517/celebrating-festival-while-menstruation/15519#15519) regarding the impurity of women during courses..Regarding sudras entering houses owned by the higher castes..that is not prohibited in Scriptures..Mostly the servants are from the sudra class and they must be allowed entry into houses to serve to start with..and to serve those belonging to the upper castes has been assigned as the only work for a sudra..So no such prohibitions..but may be the outcastes are prohibited..

Comment: Even if some brahman wrote something in Sanskrit that doesn't mean that it all is true. All your explanation is nothing more than superstitious (Andhvishvas) of earlier time people. Even Shree Ram ate fruits of Shabri (wo bhi juthe ber) and Shree krishna also had many friends in Gokul who was from low caste but still he ate with them play with them. So don't spread such things that shudra are anything like non touchable. All your explanation are being made by those brahman who had lost their true path of mankind or humanity.

Comment: @Rishabh I am not spreading anything here. All that i have posted are found in important Hindu Scriptures. If u don't like what's being said there then that's ur problem. Even u know about Ramayana and Mahabharata only because **some brahmin/saints have written text on them**..Otherwise u could not have known what had happened such long years back..

Comment: Even if some brahman wrote something in Sanskrit that doesn't mean that it all is true.--- First of all Parashara was a Mahamuni not just a Brahman so first get ur facts right..Also, if u don't believe in what he has written then why do u believe the other saints who have written Ramayana and Mahabharata? Just becoz u like whats being written by them? Also are u sure that untouchability was not present during those times?? @Rishabh

Comment: @Rickross The saint who wrote Ramayan and Mahabharat, clearly mentioned great msg of Lord Ram and krishan in they script. Lord krishan use to eat makhan with all of their low caste friends, and he even use to eat their eaten makhan (juthan). When one day Brahma sees krishan eating with low caste and even eating their juthan then he start thinking, he is truly Lord himself. How Parbrahma can eat with that low caste (shudra)? So he made up his mind to test whether he is actually Lord or not? To test him Brahma kidnapped all his friends and cows [continue....]

Comment: @Rickross and take all of them to brahmlok. He make them stayed their for one day. But brahmlok's one day is equal to many years in earth. So when Krishan didn't find their friends then by his power he came to know it was Brahma's doing. So he make many forms (clones) himself (equal to how many their friends and cows) and make them take form of their friends and cows and start living ordinary life. When after one day completed in Brahmlok (and many years completed in earth) then Brahma came to earth to check what Krishan doing without [continue...]

Comment: @Rickross his friends and cows. When he came to earth then he saw krishan was enjoying with their friends and cows. Then he got shock coz Krishan's all friends is in Brahmlok then who are with Krishan right now? He saw in Brahmlok and found their friends there and same time saw in earth and found their friends in earth as well. Brahma was so shocked and couldn't figure out whats going on. So he surrender to Narayan (Krishan) and said Please save me, Trahimam.. Then after hearing this from Brahma, Shree krishan accept his words. Brahma goes to Krishan and said [continue...]

Comment: @Rickross Please save me from your illusion (maya), I am your true Devotee, I came in existence from your nabhi. I am like your son... Please forgive me and remove you illusion and show me your true form. Then all of friends of Krishan who was at earth (krishan himself in multiple form) take back in form of krishan. Then Brahma saw all of krishan's friend on earth is actually Krishan himself. Then Krishan said to Brahma... Hey Brama Dev, You got ego inside your heart, so I wanted to remove it. You already knows that [continue...]

Comment: @Rickross All living things on earth is actually my ansh, My ansh lives in all humans and animals in form of Atma. Then how any human can be small/low and one can be great. Me himself live in every life, so every life is my form (roop), There is no difference between humans. I am for all humans equally (Don't remember all words of Shree Krishan right now). But he confront Brahma that I never differentiate between humans. For me all humans are same and I can eat juthan of humans coz they are no differ than me.

Comment: @Rickross This is what I learn by Lord Krishan's teaching which is directly conflicting with your answer. This was just one example that I have shown to you but I Have many more... I can tell you more example like this if you want :)

Comment: @Rishabh How do u know who was Krishna and what he did etc? Are u present there with him to know all that? NO of course..U know because Vyasa had written about him and his exploits..So u believe in Vyasa right?  BUt u don't believe in his father another Maharishi called Parashra? Either u believe all or u don't believe any.. Also in this answer i am not supporting untouchability etc..The Q asks why? Then i just mention the reasons the Scriptures tell us..That's all.

Comment: @Vishvam First and last thing is the dashavtar are just that: DESCENT of Maha Vishnu to re establish Dharma...as such NONE of the rules bind them.  They know very well how to conduct themselves but let no human mislead themselves that they are alliwed what Krishna did...can humans also give 700 shloka gita extempore..? Or lift Govardhan?

Answer (score 6):

Scriptures say that all people should be treated equally.

> Enlightened men are those **who see the same** in a Brahmana with learning
>   and humility, in a cow, in an elephant, and even in a dog or in an
>   eater of dog-meat.

Gita 5.18

Then there is this passage which explains how a person who sees the same in everything behaves.

> Bhishma continued [Suka said],’..By knowledge, one attains to that
>   whither there is no occasion for grief; whither one becomes freed from
>   birth and death; whither one is not subject to decrepitude; whither
>   one transcends the state of conscious existence; whither is Brahma
>   which is Supreme, Unmanifest, immutable, ever-existent, imperceptible,
>   above the reach of pain, immortal, and transcending destruction;
>   whither all become freed from the influence of all pairs of opposites
>   (like pleasure and pain, etc), as also wish or purpose. **Reaching that
>   stage, they cast equal eyes on everything, becoming universal friends
>   and devoted to the good of all the creatures.’**

Mahabharata Santi Parva Section CCXLI

Gita and Mahabharata say that one should treat all people equally by becoming universal friends of all, doing good to all, whether in a temple or outside. It is not possible to be universal friends of all if you prevent fellow Hindus from entering a temple.

There are some Smritis that say otherwise but they clearly are in conflict with the Gita. One Smriti asks molten lead to be poured in the ears of a Sudra if he dares to listen to the Vedas. Some temples do not allow lower caste people to enter temples inspired by such appalling and vicious statements. It is of course now illegal to stop any Hindu from entering a Hindu temple. Unfortunately the enforcement of the law is lax in some village areas. People who stop fellow Hindus from entering temples should be punished in exemplary fashion to stop this pernicious practice.

Comment: It's not about treating people the same, it's about seeing that their Atmas are the same.  Just because people have the same sorts of Atmas doesn't mean society treating them the same.

Comment: Good reference from BG. But why will "enlightened men" go to temples in first place?

Comment: @sv. The sanskrit verse is "vidyā-vinaya-sampanne
brāhmaṇe gavi hastini
śuni caiva śva-pāke ca
paṇḍitāḥ sama-darśinaḥ".  So, Humble people with true knowledge see all species as same.

Comment: "It is of course now illegal to stop any Hindu from entering a Hindu temple. Unfortunately the enforcement of the law is lax in some village areas." I, one the other hand, think it's quite fortunate that the government has not cracked down on all traditional temple practices.

Comment: Friends  please answer my question for what reason they are not allowing low caste ? and dont think about  today's government

Comment: @sakthi, will you shake hands with someone when you're eating ? why not ? because it's considered unclean, right ? similarly, there are lot of rules determining what is clean and unclean - and temples follow the strictest of such rules. Low caste people are not expected to stay clean because of the nature of their job e.g. it is stupid to expect a sewage cleaner or mortuary cremator to be spic-and-span all the time cos his duty demands him to be dirty. A temple priest however, has to bathe thrice a day. since dharma shastra dictates temples must be clean, they do not allow unclean persons.

Answer (score 2):

Its a myth that Sudras are not allowed into temples. Even Chandalas are allowed into temples. Sudras can even become priests in temples.

1. A pavilion is set up either in the outer courtyard of the temple or
   even beyond the main Gopuram. The deity is taken in procession and
   then seated in the pavilion to receive worship in front of all the
   devotees -Then the Vedas, Agamas, Itihasas and Puranas and
   Prabandhas are all chanted in front of devotees of all castes.
   (Isvara Samhita 12.228 – 250)
2. A Brahmana, Kshatriya, Vaishya or **Sudra who is filled with
   mindfulness of Bhagavan**, endowed with faith and devotion,
   accomplished, of a peaceful disposition, who has faith in the Vedas,
   truthful, of good behavior, learned in Pancharatra and having
   thorough knowledge of philosophy, a devotee of God and born in a
   family of devotees **shall be chosen as acharya**. (Isvara Samhita
   16.5-6 )
3. Even a person born in a **family of dog-eaters immediately becomes
   eligible to perform Vedic sacrifices if he once utters the holy name
   of the Supreme Personality of Godhead. Even if born in the families
   of dog-eaters, such persons are worshipable.** Persons who chant the
   holy name of Your Lordship **must have executed all kinds of
   austerities and fire sacrifices** and achieved all the good manners
   of the Aryans. To be chanting the holy name of Your Lordship, they
   **must have bathed at holy places of pilgrimage, studied the Vedas and fulfilled everything required.** (Srimad Bhagavatam 3.33.6–7)
4. A **Chandala who is a pure Vaishnava at heart** and who decorates
   the eleven parts of his body with Vishnu-Tilaka and sandalwood paste
   is always **worshipable, even by the best of Brahmanas**. (Padma
   Purana, Uttara Khanda 66.84)
5. If a **devotee of Vishnu, even though he be a Chandala,** is
   recollected, named, seen or **touched accidentally** by anybody, O
   dear madam, the **former purifies them.** (Varaha Purana 211.9)
6. On the outskirts of the city named Avanti lived a **Chandala. At
   night he would go to Vishnu’s temple and sing praises of Vishnu**.
   He never failed to observe this ritual...The Chandala went to the
   temple. He worshipped Vishnu and spent the night in singing Vishnu’s
   praises..([Bramha Purana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-brahma-purana/d/doc57584.html))
7. Ramanujacharya gave Panchamas the title of “Tirukkulattar” or the
   “Blessed Descendants,” and further allowed them the **privilege of
   entering into the Holy Temples.** Ramanuja opened the doors of
   religious instructions for these classes, as well as certain modes
   of ritual. **Ramanuja had already confirmed too in his own days,
   what his predecessors had ordained, viz.,the enshrinement of saints
   in the Temples, to whatever caste they may belong to**.(The Life of
   Ramanuja)

PV Kane in his History of the Dharma Sastra Vol 2 Part 1 Page 93 says

> There is no taint of untouchability when a person is touched by an
> untouchable in a temple, religious processions and marriages, in
> sacrifices, and in all festivals’ (Atri verse 249). Sātātapa quoted in
> the Smriti Candrika declares that there is no doṣa in touching
> untouchables in a village on the public road or in a religious
> procession or in an affray and the like, and also when the whole
> village is involved in a calamity. Brhaspati also remarks that there
> is no fault and so no prāyaścitta if one comes in contact with
> untouchables at a sacred place, in marriage processions and religious
> processions, in battle, when the country is invaded, or when the town
> or village is on fire. The Smṛtyārthasāra summarises the places where
> no blame in incurred on the ground of mixing with untouchables viz. in
> battle, on public roads leading to a market, in religious processions,
> in temples, in festivals, in sacrifices, at sacred places, in
> calamities or invasions of the country or village, on the banks of
> large sheets of water, in the presence of great persons, when there is
> a sudden fire or other great calamity. It is somewhat remarkable that
> the Smṛtyārthasāra speaks of untouchables entering temples.
> Nirnaya-sindhu quotes a passage of the Devī-Purāṇa that expressly
> authorizes antyajas to establish a temple of Bhairava.